# How to move video and gif from temp directory in a single file with custom header?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, filehandle

I am an intern iOS developer currently working on a camera app. The app saves video from camera and gif of the video in the temporary directory folder. My question is  how can i move both files in a single file with a custom file header which contains the length of bytes from the video and gif and then load and present the video and gif from the same file? I would be grateful if someone could provide me with an explanation or tutorial or some library. Thank you

Comment: Hi, what have you tried until now?

Comment: Hey there, well nothing in particular im still learning and exploring the FileHandle and FileManager classes.